# How to host Svelte project to file manager

Tags: host, svelte

can someone please help me to explain how to host a Svelte project to file manager. 
All I can see is a bunch of bundle files in my Build folder, but I dont understand what to upload to file manager so that I can host the site?

Comment: What is "file manager" ?

Comment: Just a web application? Or do you have a backend to deploy also?

Comment: Just web application, no backend :)

Comment: OP means how to host Svelte....Serverless. #serverless. take out the file manager from the title it will start hitting google different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple svelte web app, you only need to deploy

- the index.html
- the bundle.js
- the bundle.css
- the global.css and
- all static assets like images and fonts (if needed)

no additional libs or config files are required.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but there is no index.html file in my build folder after running npm run build. Should i pick that from the public folder instead?

Comment: Yes, of course. That's the one. I'd copy it all to a folder somewhere on my local drive and open the page from there. Check the index.html for the paths to the bundle.js (and others), put those files in the correct subfolders and open the index.html with a browser. If that works, then you know what to deploy and with which structure.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer and, probably, upvote ;)